# Check whether user has logged in TCL

Tags: web, tcl

I am developing a Web Portal using TCL/Expect . I want to check whether user has logged in or not in each and every page . I have been trying to set the environmental variable HTTP_COOKIE. It is getting set but the same value is not reflecting in the other web pages due to the fact that child process cannot set the environmental variable of the parent.At present i am using users IP to check whether user has logged in . Is there any other way to store user session details in TCL like $_SESSION[] in PHP

Comment: What web framework do you use? Is the Tcl script called as CGI? Or via SCGI? Or is it a webserver written in Tcl (like TclHTTPd, Wub, Wibble)?

Comment: I am pretty much new to this.Can you tell me how do we embedd a web server into an existing Tcl

Comment: Recommendations for which package to use are officially off-topic for Stack Overflow (under the label “let's go shopping”) but we can do it when there's one community-recommended solution. In this case, there are many. (Session management always comes down to “put things in a DB, keyed by an arbitrary ID (the session token)”.)

Comment: Ok.If i use ncgi package , is there a procedure to handle session details

Comment: You have to write your own. The problem here is that you should be able to create a unpredictable session identifier.